# How do I print the values of every file in a directory in C?

Tags: c, file, directory

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to read the files in a directory. When I call my print function it segfaults. Can someone help out? I think it has something to do with the path name but I don't know how to go about fixing it.

I know it's not something wrong with my print function because it prints regular files just fine.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
     DIR *d;
     struct dirent *dir;
     d = opendir(argv[1]);
     FILE *fp;

     if(d){
          while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL){
               if(strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") == 0)
                       continue;
               if(strcmp(dir->d_name, ".." == 0)
                       continue;

               fp = fopen(dir->d_name, "r");
               //print function on fp
          }
     }      

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: We'd need to see your print function. You say it handles regular files, but what about directories and symbolic links, and files with different permissions? If you run your program through Valgrind, it should tell you where the segfault is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must append `dir->d_name` to `argv[1]` (with a '/' of course) to create the full path to the file. Otherwise, you can only open files in the current directory. Alternatively, you can use `chdir` to change the current directory to `argv[1]`.

To avoid the segfault, you should check the return value from `fopen`. In fact, you should always check the return value from `fopen`, because it fails often, especially during development.